Python processes being leaked when using Reticulate and joblib
I'm having a issue when using joblib.Parallel through reticulate. Basically, if I have an R script call a python function that uses joblib.Parallel to parallelize running of code, and then run that R script, the Python executables are left running after the script has completed, and then at some point in the future, they get killed with the following warning being raised:
resource_tracker.py:314: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 8 leaked semlock objects to clean up at shutdown
resource_tracker.py:314: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked folder objects to clean up at shutdown

To reproduce:
Prerequisties
This needs the following packages, either globally or in your virtual environment
pip install joblib
install.packages('reticulate') (in a R interpreter)
foo.R
foo <- reticulate::import("foo")
foo$run()

And in the same directory
foo.py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def calc(i):
    return i**2

def run():
    res = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(calc)(i) for i in range(10))
    print(res)

Finally, invoke the R script using Rscript:
$ Rscript foo.R

If you run the Python script directly (calling run) then you don't get the error.
Because joblib doesn't kill the processes immediately, you get the warning some time after running, but you can tell immediately something has gone wrong by using ps -a | grep "python" -c to see how many python interpreters are left. Alternatively, you can force joblib to shut down the processors by adding this on after the Parallel call:
from joblib.externals.loky import get_reusable_executor
get_reusable_executor().shutdown(wait=True)

Also, very oddly, if you use the play button in VS code I don't see any lingering python processes, and with the above change, no errors. But I can't work out what VS Code is doing differently compared to calling R and then source('foo.R')
